# What is this component used for on this PSU cable?

Tags: power-supply, power

Regarding an AC/DC power adapter:

[image]

What are the components and what are they used for at the input and the output of the PSU cable?

I mean the following part:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either they are ferrite beads that are added onto a cheaply designed power supply to be able to legally pass electromagnetic interference testing and to be legally able to sell the device.

Or, another option is that it's just a piece of molded plastic to only give an impression of high quality product with ferrite beads being added for extra precaution against electromagnetic interference, but in reality there are no ferrites inside the plastic.

Comment: Looks like Meanwell [OWA power supply](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/D400/MW_OWA_90E_XX.pdf) which is the same as [NPF LED driver](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/D400/NPF-90_DB.pdf) without constant current and with plugs. No ferrite cores on the official datasheet...